# Python/JS/CSS: Fit a Plotly graph inside a responsive grid element

Tags: css, django, plotly-python, plotly.js

I am using Django and trying to embed Plotly plots into my HTML templates.
For testing I copied the simple examples into my `views.py`.

This is the 2nd plot:

```
# Plot 2
animals = ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']
fig2 = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23])])
plot_div2 = plot(fig2, output_type='div', include_plotlyjs=False)
```

All plots are included by the `context` dict.

```
context = {
    'plots': {
        'test1': plot_div1,
        'test2': plot_div2,
    },
}
```

In my template `home.html` there is a **responsive** Grid (12 cols). The graphs are plotted side by side (each graph is inside a 6-col element).

So one plot looks like this:

```
<div class="p-relative col-6 pd-5 border-box elevation-1 primary">
    <div class="p-relative border-box w-full">
        {{plots.test1|safe}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Parent element CSS:

```
position: relative;
grid-column-end: span 6;
padding: 1.25rem;
box-sizing: border-box;
box-shadow: ... ;
background: ...;
```

Child element CSS:

```
position: relative;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 100%;
```

**The Problem:**
The plot's height looks okay, but the plot's width is bigger than the container width.
Because the plots should be displayed inside a *responsive grid* it would make no sense to resize
the plots using **pixels**.
The attached pictures shows the problem.

[Plot overflow (Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlYZi.png)

**Edit:**
I noticed that when I resize the browser window, the plots are also resized. After resizing, the plots fit the responsive grid well. So the question is: How can I do this without resizing the browser window?

**Edit 2:**
I added two JS functions which fit the plots automatically.
*But is there a integrated Plotly function to do this? Somehow the plotly function - which is called on window resize - has to work.

Comment: "I added two JS functions which fit the plots automatically" -> do you mean you've created some workaround for this? Could you share it?

Comment: @KlaasvanSchelven Unfortunately, I no longer have the code. However, this was only a very simple workaround that I wrote. In the end it was a callback that was fired on the event onDocumentReady. Then the size of the container was read using getBoundingClientRect() and this size was passed to the plot. I may have had the plot / or parent element updated again afterwards.